# Error in Outlook VBA looping through Recipients

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an excel sheet with the following values in Range A1:B7

```
+----------------+--------------------+
| Recipient Type | Recipient Addresss |
+----------------+--------------------+
| To             | a@xyz.com          |
| To             | b@xyz.com          |
| CC             | c@xyz.com          |
| CC             | d@xyz.com          |
| BCC            | e@xyz.com          |
| BCC            | f@xyz.com          |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

I then made the following VBA Macro to add these as email recipients in Outlook

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Recipients_Data_and_Type()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olMail.Display
Dim rn As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Set rn = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1))
For Each cl In rn
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case "To"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olTo
        Case "CC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olCC
        Case "BCC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olBCC
    End Select
    i = i + 1
Next cl
End Sub
```

The problem is.. **the last recipient i.e. f@xyz.com always gets added to the To field instead of the BCC field.**
However, if I make **a dummy blank last row entry** in the table as follows
Recipient Type = BCC and Recipient Address = " "( one empty space), then the code works and adds two recipients each in the To, CC and BCC field as originally intended

What could be the reason?

Comment: In a first step you can set a breakpoint at `For Each cl In rn` and add `Debug.Print cl.Value` below. Now execute the code and when it reaches the breakpoint step through it with F8 and check the values. You should see in the immediate window the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug like this:

```
For Each cl In rn
    Debug.Print cl.Address; cl.Parent.Name
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case "To"
            Debug.Print "adding "; cl.Offset(, 1); "TO"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olTo
        Case "CC"
            Debug.Print "adding "; cl.Offset(, 1); "CC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olCC
        Case "BCC"
            Debug.Print "adding "; cl.Offset(, 1); "BCC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olBCC
    End Select
Next
```

And see whether you do not get anything interesting in the immediate window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: It did not correct the bug it still adds f@xyz.com to the To field rather than BCC. It gives the following output in the Immediate window `code` $A$1Sheet1
$A$2Sheet1
adding a@xyz.comTO
$A$3Sheet1
adding b@xyz.comTO
$A$4Sheet1
adding c@xyz.comCC
$A$5Sheet1
adding d@xyz.comCC
$A$6Sheet1
adding e@xyz.comBCC
$A$7Sheet1
adding f@xyz.comBCC `code`

Comment: @ctd2015 - the last line of what you are writing is `adding f@xyz.comBCC`. Which means that after this the `olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olBCC` should be carried out and everything should be ok. Can you try with F8?

Comment: is it working on your system?? it does not replicate on mine. On mine the f@xyz.com remains in the To even though the .Type shows as olBCC

Comment: @ctd2015 - I do not have outlook currently, cannot replicate.

Answer (score 0):

The Select Case seems to be working, but there is some issue with `Recipients.Add` method.

However if you are open to other solutions, you can try this code instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Recipients_Data_and_Type()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olMail.Display
Dim rn      As Range
Dim cl      As Range
Dim mailTo  As String
Dim mailCC  As String
Dim mailBCC As String
Dim i       As Long

i = 1
Set rn = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1))
For Each cl In rn
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case "To"
            mailTo = mailTo & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"
        Case "CC"
            mailCC = mailCC & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"
        Case "BCC"
            mailBCC = mailBCC & cl.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";"
    End Select
    i = i + 1
Next cl

olMail.To = mailTo
olMail.CC = mailCC
olMail.BCC = mailBCC
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug. When I click on Check Names there is a duplicate f@xyz.com added to the Bcc.

I tried ResolveAll in the code and f@xyz.com was in the Bcc not the To.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Recipients_Data_and_Type()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olMail.Display
Dim rn As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Set rn = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1))
For Each cl In rn
    Select Case cl.Value
        Case "To"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olTo
        Case "CC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olCC
        Case "BCC"
            olMail.Recipients.Add(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value).Type = olBCC
    End Select
    i = i + 1
Next cl

olMail.Recipients.ResolveAll

End Sub
```